# How do I use OpenVPN with Tor?

Tags: raspbian

I have a personal OpenVPN server setup on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. Right now, my traffic goes Computer > Raspberry > Internet, but I'd like to make it go Computer > TOR Network > Raspberry > Internet. How would I configure OpenVPN to do this? Thanks!

Comment: This question is primarily about configuring OpenVPN.

Comment: May I ask what particular reason you have to use OpenVPN over Tor instead of Tor directly. I believe the former cloud be a bad idea anonymity-wise depending on your use case.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't cable around it?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, I do **NOT** think this is a good idea if you depend on Tor for anonymity in the Internet. If you want to connect to your private network without anyone knowing from where you connect, the use of Tor might be legitimate. However, if you connect to the Internet, you'll only hide your current location but very likely not your identity.

If still want to do it, something like this should work (untested and most of it assumes your running a Debian based distro and that OpenVPN is already working):

1. install a HTTP proxy (example uses polipo)

   ```
   apt install polipo
   ```
2. configure Polipo to use Tor (/etc/polipo/config)

   ```
   socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
   socksProxyType = socks5
   ```
3. edit your [OpenVPN config](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/sample/sample-config-files/client.conf#L75) to use HTTP proxy (/etc/openpvn/${CLIENT_NAME}.conf)

   ```
   http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
   http-proxy localhost 8123
   ```